# Дебаг C++ кода в VS Code

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-code

При попытке запуска для дебага (F5, брекпойнт поставлен) кода на C++ в Visual Studio Code (ОС Ubuntu 18.04) возникает ошибка.
Текст:

```
Unable to start debugging. Program path '/home/aleksey/cpp/test' is missing or invalid.
GDB failed with message: "/home/aleksey/cpp/test": not in executable format: Формат файла не распознан
This may occur if the process's executable was changed after the process was started, such as when installing an update. Try re-launching the application or restarting the machine.
```

Предлагает открыть launch.json. Его содержимое:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "cpp build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "cpp build active file",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
        }
    ]
}
```

Что я делаю:
1) Есть тестовый файл с кодом (test.cpp)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

2) Выполняю сборку (Ctrl+Shift+B, компилятор g++). Получаю файл test (в консоли он работает как надо).
3) При попытке запустить этот файл в режиме дебага (F5), получаю текст ошибки. Пробовал перезапустить, пересобрать, прописать путь в launch.json (configurations.program). Запускал без брекпойнтов и с брекпойнтом на строке 7 (return 0;).

Из-за чего может возникать проблема, и как ее исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в компиляторе.
Нужно было настроить, через что компилировать.
В файле launch.json "preLaunchTask": "cpp build active file" - задача, выполняемая до запуска файла на дебаг.
Задачи прописываются в tasks.json. Он лежит в папке .vscode проекта.
Фрагмент моего файла:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "cpp build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/cpp",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        }
}
```

Нас интересует пункт label. Он содержит имя задачи. Выбираем рабочий компилятор (у меня g++), копируем содержимое, вставляем в preLaunchTask файла launch.json.
Строка должна выглядеть примерно так: "preLaunchTask": "g++ build active file".
После этого дебаг заработал.  Возникла другая проблема - доступным через Ctrl+Shift+B остался только g++. Вылечилось ручной правкой tasks.json (чтобы задача была доступна из меню сборки, она должна иметь строку "group": "build".